# What's the default webpage DTD if not mentioned in doctype?

Tags: html, doctype

Seems there are quite some differences in the webpage rendering due to the Doctype setting in the first line(normally) of a web page.

So I wonder what would be the default DTD if not mentioned

For example, if simply put it this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Seems there are quite some differences in the webpage rendering due to the Doctype setting in the first line(normally) of a web page.

Browsers use Doctypes as a magic string to switch between [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and Standards mode (and Almost Standards mode). You need a real SGML/XML parser to care about the DTD.

> So I wonder what would be the default DTD if not mentioned

If there is a public identifier but no system identifier, then the parser is expected to look up the DTD in a local catalogue.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ — Formal Public Identifier
```

What you have, however, is the HTML 5 Doctype, which is designed be *nothing more* than the magic mode switching string. HTML 5 is explicitly not SGML based. Consequently, there is no DTD associated with it at all.

Answer (score 0):

[That's the HTML5 doctype declaration](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype).